# Usage of threading.Timer with async based functions

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda, python-asyncio

I'm working on a Discord bot with Python and it queues music from YouTube, i'm working on something to autoqueue songs when the player is stopped, while all of the code works perfectly, the only problem is me not being able to check if the player is playing or not every 15 seconds

```
    async def cmd_autoqueue(self,message, player,channel,author, permissions, leftover_args):

     print("autoq ran")
     if started == True:

       if player.is_stopped:
         await self.cmd_autoqadd(player, channel, author, permissions,leftover_args,song_url=last_url)
       threading.Timer(15.0,await self.cmd_autoqueue(message, player,channel,author, permissions, leftover_args)).start()
```

i did realise that

```
threading.Timer(15.0,await self.cmd_autoqueue(message, player,channel,author, permissions, leftover_args)).start()
```

calls the function, and if i wanted to pass it as something that would be called later i would use lambda: but , async lambda?

also started boolean is managed by other stuff so well its there for the sake of the 'if', here in this question

Solution:

```
    async def cmd_autoqueue(self,message, player,channel,author, permissions, leftover_args):
    global started
    print("loop")
    if started == True:
       await asyncio.sleep(15) 
       if player.is_stopped:
         await self.cmd_autoqadd(player, channel, author, permissions,leftover_args,song_url=last_url)
       await self.cmd_autoqueue(message, player,channel,author, permissions, leftover_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use loop.call_later, that returns you an asyncio-compatible handler to cancel the task.

class YourClass:
    def **init**(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._check_handler = None

```
def schedule_check(self):
    self._check_handler = loop.call_later(
        15 * 60,  # Every 15 minutes
        self._loop.create_task, self._periodic_check())

def stop_checking(self):
    self._check_handler.cancel()    

async def start_player(self):
    await do something()
    if not check_handler:
        schedule_check()

async def stop_player(self):
    await do something()
    self.stop_checking()

async def _periodic_check(self):
    await do_something()
    self._schedule_check()
```

To pass a function (that needs some parameters) as a parameter to another function, that doesn't allow you to pass the parameters, you can bind the parameters using functools.partial.