# async functions as callback for threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py

I'm having trouble with using threading package in Python. I want to create discord bot that sends message after some time. Previously i was using `time.sleep()` but it makes my bot useless for a given period of time. I found that i can use `threading.Timer()` but I can't make it work.
Sample code:

```
async def send_sth(channel):
    await channel.send("some message")


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'send sth':
        timer = threading.Timer(10.0, send_sth, [message.channel])
        timer.start()
```

after 10 seconds i have error saying `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_sth' was never awaited`. Is it possible to run async functions with Timer callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607492/usage-of-threading-timer-with-async-based-functions

Comment: Why? Why not simply put an `await asyncio.sleep(10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than i thought

```
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'send sth':
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await message.channel.send("some message")
```